# How can I see the parameters of a IQueryable expression

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, linq-to-entities

If I do

```
var p1 = "33326";
var query = Db.Customers.Where(x=>x.AddrZip==p1);

var sqlStatement = query.ToString(); 
            /*
             sqlStatement =
                SELECT 
                [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
                [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
                [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
                [Extent1].[Company] AS [Company]                    
                FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
                WHERE [Extent1].[AddrZip] = @p__linq__0
             */
```

note at the end of the query I see `@p__linq__0` . where is that paramter on `query`? I am looking to find something like `query.Parameters`

### Edit

**Sorry I forgot to mention that Db is of type `DbContext` and is not `DataContext`**

Answer (score 2):

The `IQueryable` itself does not know anything about parameters - it is more general interface, and notion of parameters depends on particular implementation.

However you can use `DataContext.GetCommand` method to inspect the resulting command. The resulting object `DbCommand` has the collection of parameters:

```
DbCommand command = Db.GetCommand(query);
var parameters = command.DbParametersCollection;
```

Comment: Db is of type `DbContext` I cannot seem to find that method `GetCommand` perhaps the method is static?

Comment: Thats exactly what I need cannot find the `GetCommand` method +1 for the help I know I am close on finding the solution!

Comment: Andrei the reason is because Db is of type `DbContext` and is not `DataContext`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the event CommandFinished  for the context Look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx) for more details

```
 context.CommandFinished += (sender, e) =>
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Command has finished: {0}", e.ToTraceString());
  };
```